# Birthday field validation of user in rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation, datetime

I added birthday to the users of my web app and am having trouble with the validations I want. It is a boyscout management app and I want scouts who sign up to have their age be between 12-18, but since birthdays are a new addition there are already scouts who do not have birthdays in my database. Thus, I would like to do something like `before_create :validate_birthday`, but I am not sure how to write that validation function. I believe it would be something like

```
def validate_birthday
  if self.has_role?(:scout)
    if !self.has_valid_dob?
      errors.add(:birthday, "invalid. Must be 12-18 years of age")
    end
  else
    if self.birthday.to_date != "06/06/1944".to_date
      self.birthday = "06/06/1944".to_date
    end
  end
end
```

and

```
def has_valid_dob?
  self.birthday.to_date > (18.years.ago).to_date && self.birthday < (12.years.ago).to_date
end
```

Now running this does not throw an error, but the error message does not appear saying "Birthday invalid. Must be 12-18 years of age". I think I'm close, but I'm not sure where to go from here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: User should have a line like `validate :validate_birthday`, right?

Comment: @Phlip doing that causes an error when we update another field of a scout with a blank birthday. For example, if an administrator wants to set the scout to eagle once they've finished their project and the scout was in the database before I added birthdays, I get a nil class on birthday error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use a `Proc`:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  validate :valid_age, if: proc { |u| u.birthdate.present? }

  protected

  def valid_age
    return if valid_date_range.include?(birthdate)
    errors.add(:birthdate, 'invalid. Must be 12-18 years of age')
  end

  def valid_date_range
    maximum_date..minimum_date
  end

  def minimum_date
    12.years.ago.to_date
  end

  def maximum_date
    18.years.ago.to_date
  end
end
```

Comment: This looks like what I need. I'll try implementing it tonight and let you know how it goes.

Comment: Great! Be aware that I'm not taking into account the role of the user... I'm assuming that all `users` are `scouts`.

Comment: This works great! I took your proc example and made a custom validation for birthday presence on scouter sign-up (vs district eagle rep creation by an admin - both are users): `validates :birthday, presence: true, if: proc { |u| u.has_role?(:scout) && u.id.blank? }` is there a better way to go about that? Thanks for the help!

Comment: I think is OK if you don't plan to have more user types. A better approach could be create a subclass for scout, district rep, etc, and add specific validations for each.